# How to receive async result in a View from a function in Model?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm loading my `Image` from a URL:

**EditProfile.swift**

```
struct EditableCircleImage: View {
    @ObservedObject var storage = Storages()
    let key: String
    let imgName: String?
    @State var image: Image = Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
    @State var uiImage: UIImage?
    @State var showImagePicker = false

    let uid = UserAuth().uid ?? "<uid>"
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            image
                .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(height: 200)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 2))
            Button(action: { self.showImagePicker.toggle() }){
                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(height: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)

            }.offset(x: 40, y: 50)
            .onAppear {
                self.loadImageFromUrl(imgName: self.imgName)
            }
        }
        
    }

    func loadImageFromUrl(imgName: String?) {
        guard let imgName = imgName else {
            return
        }
        print("imgName: \(imgName)")
        let url = URL(string: "http://app-8kui4.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/users/\(uid)/\(imgName)")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, err in
            print("DATA: \(data) | ERR: \(err)")
            if let data = data, let uiImage = UIImage(data: data)  {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()

    }
}
```

I need to re-use the exact same function `loadImageFromUrl()` in another view.

**ProfileView.swift**

```
struct CircleImage : View {
    let imgURL: String?
    @State var image: Image = Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
    let uid = UserAuth().uid ?? "<uid>"
    var body: some View {
        image
            .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(height: 200)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 2))
            .onAppear {
            // loadImageFromUrl()
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

I can't add `loadImageFromUrl()` in a Model as it loses the reference to the `Image` in the view. I don't want to add a `@Published` property in a Model and reference the image from there as that is not dynamic and scalable - I simply want to pass a reference to my `CircleImage` struct to a Model which then changes the `CircleImage` `Image`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass reference to `CircleImage` because it is not reference type, it is a value type struct, is-a `View` protocol.

As `loadImageFromUrl` does not depend actually on anything in view, put it at top level (for reusability) and add callback in arguments:

```
func loadImageFromUrl(imgName: String?, completion: @escaping (UIImage)->()) {
    guard let imgName = imgName else {
        return
    }
    print("imgName: \(imgName)")
    let url = URL(string: "http://app-8kui4.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/users/\(uid)/\(imgName)")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, err in
        print("DATA: \(data) | ERR: \(err)")
        if let data = data, let uiImage = UIImage(data: data)  {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(Image(uiImage: uiImage))
            }
        }
        
    }.resume()
}
```

so now you can reuse it in both views (of course it assumed that `CircleImage` will have some `imgName` property)

```
.onAppear {
    loadImageFromUrl(imgName: self.imgName) { self.image = $0 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension View to make all class extend from View also have method loadImageFromUrl.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let key: String = ""
    let imgName: String = "image"
    @State var image: Image = Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
    @State var uiImage: UIImage?
    @State var showImagePicker = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            image
                .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(height: 200)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 2))
            Button(action: { self.showImagePicker.toggle() }){
                Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(height: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)

            }.offset(x: 40, y: 50)
            .onAppear {
                self.loadImageFromUrl(imgName: self.imgName) { (image) in
                    self.image = Image(uiImage: image)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            
    }
}

extension View {
    func loadImageFromUrl(imgName: String?, completion: @escaping (UIImage)->()) {
        guard let imgName = imgName else {
            return
        }
        print("imgName: \(imgName)")
        let url = URL(string: "http://app-8kui4.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/users)")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, err in
            print("DATA: \(data) | ERR: \(err)")
            if let data = data, let uiImage = UIImage(data: data)  {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(uiImage)
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
}
```